# Can't run simple python reddit program?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

Here is the python reddit program, the code is 100% fine. It's from a tutorial website.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit('bot1')

subreddit = reddit.subreddit("learnpython")

for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=5):
print("Title: ", submission.title)
print("Text: ", submission.selftext)
print("Score: ", submission.score)
print("---------------------------------\n")
```

When I run it I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Top3Links.py", line 4, in <module>
reddit = praw.Reddit('bot1')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/praw/reddit.py", line 105, in __init__
**config_settings)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/praw/config.py", line 64, in __init__
self.custom = dict(Config.CONFIG.items(site_name), **settings)
File
```

"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 347, in items
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'bot1'
Eric-MacBook-Pro:PythonRedditBot Eric$

It maybe has something to do with installing python 3.5 any help would be amazing.

Comment: I can say for sure that the bot requires python3, but you are using python2

Comment: How can I just switch it..?

Comment: It looks you neglected to set up your `bot1` config file.

Comment: its set up, I wrote a python reddit program a couple months back, but I installed the new python and everything went to shit

Comment: Make sure you open this in IDLE for python 3 and then try running the code.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a config file for this module. Check out the documentation:
https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/configuration/prawini.html

According to the documentation, you need a `praw.ini` file, containing a section like this:

```
[bot1]
client_id=Y4PJOclpDQy3xZ
client_secret=UkGLTe6oqsMk5nHCJTHLrwgvHpr
password=pni9ubeht4wd50gk
username=fakebot1
```

The source may also be informative: https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/blob/master/praw/reddit.py#L79

Comment: I went to the reddit.py file and pasted the code on that github, and its still giving the same error.

Comment: @ItachiSan I just edited my post. I think you need a praw.ini file.